# Don't let deployments cancel file uploads

Tags: node.js, deployment

We have an application that accepts file uploads from the user.

Whenever we deploy our application we stop the application process and start it again. All lengthy processing is done before we actually stop the application so the actual downtime is fairly small (a few seconds).

However, when stopping the process we also kill active requests to our application (i.e. file uploads).

What would be a good way to handle this? I have a few ideas:

- Extract the file upload handler into a separate service?
- Make the restart more "intelligent" and tell the processes to not accept any new requests and wait for the currently active requests to stop before killing the process

Answer (score 0):

You've just listed two of essentially three solutions I can think of :-)
The third would be a multi-tier deployment with a smart load balancer and deploy process smart enough to know what node to restart and when.
If it is a smaller scale app with no significant impact, I would go to what seems to me simpler version: track active downloads and monitor this on restart. Maintain just one app, you know? But it makes the upload logic more complex.

However, if the uploads are important enough, and they seem to be, it may be worth it to extract it to a separate service. Not just because of new deploy, but also to protect you from unexpected crashes and shutdowns. You would then have to decide a way to communicate completed uploads from the service though, and also handle the client response etc.

On my view, one app to maintain and deploy is simpler then two, but of course also a bit less robust.

So the answer really depends on your needs and resources, right?

Comment: Although the question seems a bit vague, not _technically_ specific enough, it's an interesting one.

Comment: Are there example documentations of architectures of common used services that you can study? This would be pretty interesting to read. I remember a post by Soundcloud about how they scaled their architecture and documented the key systems.